# Visual studio 2013 create file type association

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, file-type

I am creating my own desktop app in visual studio 2013, C#. I made few windows forms and before further progress and finalizing my software I would like to test setup thing and file association.

I am wondering should i use option **Visual Studio installer - Setup
project** or **Setup and Deployment - InstallShield** ?

With which is better to create setup which automatically set filetype
association? Is there some quick efficient way?

For file type association do I need to modify my own registry or I can
set it up on the installer somehow?? 
This filetype thing confuses me and I dont know how to set it up. For example, I want to save my work under name *aaaaa.something*, how to automaticaly associate my program with filetype *.something*, register that on windows and link with my program?

Comment: You need an installer, only time you get the permission to tinker with the user's registry.   Sure, a Setup project is fine.  It is a built-in capability, use View > Editor > File Types.  Then right-click and Add.

Comment: thank you! I managed to do it this way and it works. No need to mess up with registry